# Replacing image in TKinter GUI using canvas.itemconfig only works twice

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas

I have a GUI with a canvas on it and 2 buttons. When I click each button I need the image to change (go forwards or backwards through a list of images). Buttons work, image is correct however only pastes whole image the first two times,  and after that only the top 10-20% is.
This is the function I am using to change the image:

```
def next_image():
    global c
    c += 1
    CNext = get_image(c)
    canvas.itemconfig(image_container, image=CNext)
    canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(ALL))
    win.mainloop()
    return 0
```

The scrollbar line is just to update the scrollbar as the images have different heights. The code to get the previous image is almost identical. The get_image function also works fine. I should also say that the CNext variable is a ImageTk object.

```
win = Tk()
win.geometry("1000x1000")

frame = Frame(win, width=1000, height=1000)
frame.pack()
frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

scroll = Scrollbar(frame, jump=1)
scroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)

canvas = Canvas(frame, bd=0, yscrollcommand=scroll.set, width=900, height=950)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(ALL))
scroll.config(command=canvas.yview)

nextB = Button(win, text="Next Chapter", command=lambda: next_image())
nextB.pack()

prevB = Button(win, text="Previous Chapter", command=lambda: prev_image())
prevB.pack()
```

This is the GUI code. Its very bare bones but I will make it look nice later once I have fixed the actual code issues.

```
img = get_image(0)
image_container = canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=img, anchor="n")
canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox(ALL))
win.mainloop()
```

This is the code that creates the container after the GUI has been made and also starts the GUI.
Please let me know if you have any ideas as to why it works twice and then doesn't. If you cant replicate it then let me know and I will try and help.

Comment: Your code does not run. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to include any imports and test data needed for it to run.

Comment: This probably isn't your actual problem, but you absolutely should not have `win.mainloop()` inside your Button's click function - the call at the top level is the only one you need.

Comment: Function next_image requires 'c' and 'img' to be global, also you are mixing pack and grid managers.